# Kafka Stream DSL groupby() vs Processor API performance tradeoff

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Kafka Streams DSL groupBy() operation can lead to repartitioning based on a new key chosen

In this, skewing or the possibility of repartitioning data to a single partition is possible

This is a significant performance bottleneck in the case of counting messages over a day

Trying Processor API with a KeyValueStore (Persistent)
Where Record Key and Value both can be accessed and the key can be changed.

And context.forward() allows to forward this changed record out from process()

This seems much more performant - as it doesn't involve repartition topic creation

What is the drawback of this use case? Is it not resilient - because of state wipeout? And it's not being backed by a changelog topic?

Please suggest.